# How to check a radiobutton in PDF form using PDFBox in Java

Tags: java, pdf, radio-button, pdfbox

How to check a Radio button in Form - PDf using PDFbox in Java

I have a piece of code for checking a check box but couldn't able to do the same with
Class PDRadioCollection

```
 PDDocument fdeb = null;

        fdeb = PDDocument.load("C:\\Users\\347702\\Desktop\\complaintform.pdf");

        PDAcroForm form = fdeb.getDocumentCatalog().getAcroForm();
        PDField feld3 = form.getField("loan");
        ((PDCheckbox) feld3).check();
        fdeb.save("C:\\Users\\347702\\Desktop\\complaintform.pdf");
        fdeb.close();
```

Can any one help me out 
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution should be as follows.  Get the name of the radio collection field instead of the specific button field you are trying to set and then set the value of the checkbox field which needs to be set.  The `setValue()` method should uncheck all the other values.

```
PDRadioCollection coverage = theForm.getField("radio collection");
coverage.setValue("loan");
```

Now if that does not work (and I have seen some buzz about that in earlier versions), an alternative, but less desirable approach would be to get all the kids of the radio collection and iterate through them.  You call `check()` on the `PDCheckbox` kid you are interested in setting and call `unCheck()` on all the others.  So something like this:

```
PDRadioCollection coverage = theForm.getField("radio collection");
kids = coverage.getKids();
for (Object kid : kids) {
   if (kid instanceof PDCheckbox) {
      PDCheckbox checkbox = (PDCheckbox) kid;
      String partialName = checkbox.getPartialName();
      if (partialName.equals("loan")) {
         checkbox.check();
      } else {
         checkbox.unCheck();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: +1, this helped resolve an issue where I got "Expected a Name Object" errors after using PDFBox to fill out a form with radio buttons. If I just called `field.setValue()` the correct radio button would be selected, but I would get the error when I tried to submit the form. Calling the `check()` method resolved the error. Thanks.